# Not getting Client side encryption with .net S3

Tags: c#, encryption, amazon-s3

I have started using the sdk from AWS for S3 and everything says I should be getting client side encryption for the uploads, but when I check it with S3 browser it only shows server side encryption, what am I doing wrong?

I am using amazon's encryption key service and the user has full rights to encrypt using those keys.

Thanks!

```
static string bucketName = "mybucket";
static EncryptionMaterials encryptionMaterials = new EncryptionMaterials(RSA.Create());
static AmazonS3EncryptionClient client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2, encryptionMaterials);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     using (client)
     {
         try
         {
             PutObjectRequest putRequest1 = new PutObjectRequest
             {
                 BucketName = bucketName,
                 FilePath = @"C:\abc\def.pdf",
                 Key = "def.pdf",
                 ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AWSKMS
             };
             client.PutObject(putRequest1);
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you see in the console that seems wrong, and what exactly do you believe you should see, instead?  Please provide some links to the "everything" that says you should be seeing what you expect to see.

Comment: in looking at the sdk api's and this website http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/TxL15A0QZMD38D/Client-Side-Data-Encryption-with-AWS-SDK-for-NET-and-Amazon-S3  I don't have any output to the console window, the program simply uploads and exits.  I thought when I viewed the file using the S3 browser that it would client side encryption as true. Is this just to transport to S3 like using an SSL connection?

Comment: I'm working through this currently now, but it looks like you are mixing client and server-side encryption.  The materials provider needs a key for the client to use.  From what I can tell the .net sdk does not currently support KMS with client-side encryption.  I posted in the AWS developer forum under .net in case you want to chime in there.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem several months ago but this was solved by introducing SymmetricAlgorithm and ICryptoTransform implementations to support KMS. These transparently encrypt and decrypt the envelope key using the KMS service and the specified CMK.

```
public class KMSAlgorithm : SymmetricAlgorithm
{
    private IAmazonKeyManagementService _client;
    private string _keyId;

    public KMSAlgorithm(IAmazonKeyManagementService client)
    {
        this._client = client;
    }

    public KMSAlgorithm(IAmazonKeyManagementService client, string keyId)
        : this(client)
    {
        this._keyId = keyId;
    }

    public override ICryptoTransform CreateDecryptor()
    {
        return new KMSCryptoTransform.Decryptor(_client);
    }

    public override ICryptoTransform CreateDecryptor(byte[] rgbKey, byte[] rgbIV)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override ICryptoTransform CreateEncryptor()
    {
        return new KMSCryptoTransform.Encryptor(_client, _keyId);
    }

    public override ICryptoTransform CreateEncryptor(byte[] rgbKey, byte[] rgbIV)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void GenerateIV()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void GenerateKey()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public abstract class KMSCryptoTransform : ICryptoTransform
{
    protected IAmazonKeyManagementService _client;
    protected string _keyId;

    public KMSCryptoTransform(IAmazonKeyManagementService client)
    {
        this._client = client;
    }

    public KMSCryptoTransform(IAmazonKeyManagementService client, string keyId)
        : this(client)
    {
        this._keyId = keyId;
    }

    public bool CanReuseTransform
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public bool CanTransformMultipleBlocks
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public int InputBlockSize
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public int OutputBlockSize
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public int TransformBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount, byte[] outputBuffer, int outputOffset)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public abstract byte[] TransformFinalBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount);

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public class Decryptor : KMSCryptoTransform
    {
        public Decryptor(IAmazonKeyManagementService client)
            : base(client) { }

        public override byte[] TransformFinalBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount)
        {
            return _client.Decrypt(new DecryptRequest()
            {
                CiphertextBlob = new MemoryStream(inputBuffer, inputOffset, inputCount))
            }).Plaintext.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public class Encryptor : KMSCryptoTransform
    {
        public Encryptor(IAmazonKeyManagementService client, string keyId)
            : base(client, keyId) { }

        public override byte[] TransformFinalBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount)
        {
            return _client.Encrypt(new EncryptRequest()
            {
                KeyId = _keyId,
                Plaintext = MemoryStream(inputBuffer, inputOffset, inputCount))
            }).CiphertextBlob.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

This KMSAlgorithm was used this in place of Aes.Create() in the EncryptionMaterials constructor which was in turn used in the AmazonS3EncryptionClient constructor like so.

```
var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonKeyManagementServiceClient();
using (var algorithm = new KMSAlgorithm(client, "CustomerMasterKeyIdOrAlias"))
{
    var materials = new EncryptionMaterials(algorithm);
    var s3client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(materials);

    s3client.PutObject(new PutObjectRequest()
    {
        BucketName = "YourBucketName",
        Key = "YourKeyName",
        InputStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Secret Message")),
    });
}

using (var algorithm = new KMSAlgorithm(client))
{
    var materials = new EncryptionMaterials(algorithm);
    var s3client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(materials);

    var obj = s3client.GetObject(new GetObjectRequest()
    {
        BucketName = "YourBucketName",
        Key = "YourKeyName"
    });
}
```

Notice that the CMK id or alias doesn't have to be explicitly specified to decrypt the envelope key only to encrypt the envelope key.

This answer is also posted in the [Amazon Web Services Developer Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=608416#608416).