# AWS S3 Client-Side Crypto with KMS in .NET issues ProtocolViolationException on last part transferred

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services

The following code attempts to copy a 17MB test file to an S3 bucket using multi-part transfer, client-side envelope encryption and the Amazon KMS service to handle the data encryption key.  The multi-part block size is 5MB.

Upon transferring the last (partial) block, and **only** if the `IsLastPart` flag is set to `true`, the call to `UploadPart` generates a `System.Net.ProtocolViolationException` indicating: `Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified.`

This suggests that the Content-Length html header was not updated to reflect the necessary "pad bytes" added by the encryption engine to the last cipher block for proper alignment.  As a result, when those final bytes were added, they exceeded the given Content-Length and generated this error.

If `IsLastPart` is **not** set (i.e. left `false`), then the operation succeeds, but upon downloading and decrypting the operation also fails.

NOTE: The `KmsAlgorithm` class is not provided by the AWS .NET SDK.  This class comes from another Stack Overflow [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540088/not-getting-client-side-encryption-with-net-s3) because the .NET version of the AWS SDK does not provide a [connector class](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=592027) between KMS and S3 to support envelope encryption as the Java SDK does.

So what is the proper way to send multi-part uploads to S3 with client-side encryption and KMS managed keys?

```
    static string bucketName = "*****************************";
    static string keyName = "test.encrypted.bin";
    static string uploadSourcePath = "c:\\temp\\test.bin";
    static long partSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    static String uploadId = "";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (checkRequiredFields())
        {
            String cmkId = "************************************";

            // Prepare our KMS client and kmsAlgorithm
            using (AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient kmsClient = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient())
            using (KMSAlgorithm kmsAlgo = new KMSAlgorithm(kmsClient, cmkId))
            {
                // Generate the encryption materials object with the algorithm object
                EncryptionMaterials encryptionMaterials = new EncryptionMaterials(kmsAlgo);

                // Now prepare an S3 crypto client
                using (AmazonS3EncryptionClient cryptoClient = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(encryptionMaterials))
                {
                    // Initiate the multipart upload request specifying the bucket and key values
                    InitiateMultipartUploadResponse initResp = cryptoClient.InitiateMultipartUpload(
                        new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest()
                        {
                            BucketName = bucketName,
                            Key = keyName
                        });

                    uploadId = initResp.UploadId;

                    long fileLength = new FileInfo(uploadSourcePath).Length;
                    long contentLength = fileLength;
                    long bytesRemaining = fileLength;


                    List<PartETag> partETags = new List<PartETag>();
                    int partNumber = 0;

                    while (bytesRemaining > 0)
                    {
                        long transferSize = bytesRemaining > partSize ? partSize : bytesRemaining;
                        long partIndex = fileLength - bytesRemaining;

                        partNumber++;

                        UploadPartResponse resp =
                            cryptoClient.UploadPart(
                                new UploadPartRequest()
                                {
                                    BucketName = bucketName,
                                    Key = keyName,
                                    FilePath = uploadSourcePath,
                                    FilePosition = partIndex,
                                    PartSize = transferSize,
                                    PartNumber = partNumber,
                                    UploadId = uploadId,
                                    IsLastPart = transferSize < AwsS3FileSystemSample1.Program.partSize
                                });

                        partETags.Add( new PartETag( partNumber, resp.ETag ));

                        bytesRemaining -= transferSize;
                    }

                    // Now complete the transfer
                    CompleteMultipartUploadResponse compResp = cryptoClient.CompleteMultipartUpload(
                        new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest()
                        {
                            Key = keyName,
                            BucketName = bucketName,
                            UploadId = initResp.UploadId,
                            PartETags = partETags
                        });
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Apologies for any errors and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much testing and a little code spelunking on git hub in the AWS SDK for .NET source code the magic secret here is setting the **PartSize** member of **UploadPartRequest** to zero (0) when setting the **IsLastPart** member to true.

Exactly why this works is a matter for some debate.  Since the data of the last part is typically padded by the crypto-engine to meet a cipher block boundary, the actual Content-Length is unknown until after encryption completes.  Perhaps setting **PartSize** to zero allows the underlying code to set **Content-Length** to the padded length of the cipher-text rather than the value give in **PartSize**.  Why this isn't done automatically when **IsLastPart** is set to true is a mystery.

In any event, the following summary may help.  When using client-side encryption and multi-part uploads, set the **PartSize** member to zero (0) and **IsLastPart** to true when uploading the last part of an object's data.

This code fragment might help.

```
      while (bytesRemaining > 0)
      {
          long transferSize = bytesRemaining > partSize ? partSize : bytesRemaining;
          long partIndex = fileLength - bytesRemaining;

          bytesRemaining -= transferSize;
          bool isLastPart = bytesRemaining == 0;

          partNumber++;

          UploadPartResponse resp =
              cryptoClient.UploadPart(
                  new UploadPartRequest()
                  {
                      BucketName   = bucketName,
                      Key          = keyName,
                      FilePath     = uploadSourcePath,
                      FilePosition = partIndex,
                      PartSize     = isLastPart ? 0 : transferSize,
                      PartNumber   = partNumber,
                      UploadId     = uploadId,
                      IsLastPart   = isLastPart 
                  });

          partETags.Add( new PartETag( partNumber, resp.ETag ));
      }
```

I hope this helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for trying to use to my implementation in the linked post.

Although I haven't read anything to explicitly support this, I think the Amazon S3 Encryption Client might be incompatible with Multipart Uploads. Although it's not definitive, I haven't been able to find a Java example (which the SDK has a KMS implementation for) using both the Amazon S3 Encryption Client on Multipart Uploads. The reason I have my doubts is that the file is encrypted using chain blocking and if each part of a Multipart Upload is encrypted piecemeal, the chain blocking would be broken and the individual initialization vectors for each piece would be lost for decryption.

I guess the only way to know is to test it out with Java first to be sure.

Comment: Hi Alton, I am very grateful for your implementation and it works exactly as you describe.  Well done.  You are correct about the block chaining, and after digging into the source code for their .NET Transfer Utility on git hub, I see that they explicitly prevent "parallel" multi-part uploads when using encryption.

Comment: Further inspection of that source shows that on the last block of a multi-part upload, they set the isLastPart flag AND set the partSize value to zero (0).  When I made this minor change, the upload succeeded and a subsequent download also succeeded.  So it would seem that the "magic" sauce is to set the partSize to zero in the request on the last part when setting isLastPart to "true".  Exactly why this works is a matter for conjecture, but so far it appears to solve the problem.  After a bit more testing, I will go ahead and write it up as the "answer" though  there are no supporting docs.